# Separate hour and minutes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column for time, but it hasn't been separated by `:` or any thing. It looks like this:

```
  person      time
   1            356
   1            931
   1            2017
   1            2103
   2            256
   2            1031
   2            1517
   2            2206
```

How do I separate them?

Comment: Are the last two digits always minutes?

Comment: yes you can assume last two digits always are minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways of approaching the issue. Which method you choose depends on your desired output.

For example, you could use `stringr::str_split` to split `time` into a `list` vector of hours and minutes using a positive look-ahead

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(time = str_split(time, "(?=\\d{2}$)"))
#  person   time
#1      1  3, 56
#2      1  9, 31
#3      1 20, 17
#4      1  2, 13
#5      2  2, 56
#6      2 10, 31
#7      2 15, 17
#8      2  2, 26
```

Or we can use `tidyr::separate` to create two new columns `hours` and `minutes`

```
df %>% separate(time, c("hours", "minutes"), sep = "(?=\\d{2}$)")
#  person hours minutes
#1      1     3      56
#2      1     9      31
#3      1    20      17
#4      1     2      13
#5      2     2      56
#6      2    10      31
#7      2    15      17
#8      2     2      26
```

---

In response to your comment you could use `stringr::str_replace`

```
df %>% mutate(time = str_replace(time, "(?=\\d{2}$)", ":"))
#  person  time
#1      1  3:56
#2      1  9:31
#3      1 20:17
#4      1  2:13
#5      2  2:56
#6      2 10:31
#7      2 15:17
#8      2  2:26
```

And the same in base R using `sub`

```
transform(df, time = sub("(?=\\d{2}$)", ":", time, perl = TRUE))
```

giving the same result.

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text = "
person      time
  1            356
  1            931
  1            2017
  1            213
  2            256
  2            1031
  2            1517
  2            226", header = T)
```

Comment: @sherek_66 Please see my edited example using `str_replace`.

Comment: Why is it 2 and not 22? `2206`

Comment: @NelsonGon OP specified that the last two digits should always be minutes

Comment: Yes but the time is 2206, did I miss something?

Comment: @NelsonGon Ah now I see what you mean. OP changed the sample data (check the edits). When I posted my answer the sample data had `"226"`.

Comment: OK, no worries. Just wanted to check if I missed something.

Comment: @NelsonGon No problem:-) I was also confused until I noticed the edit.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `strptime` with `sprintf` in `base R`

```
df[c("hour", "min")] <- unclass(strptime(sprintf("%04d00", df$time), 
          "%H%M%S"))[c('hour', 'min')]
df
#  person time hour min
#1      1  356    3  56
#2      1  931    9  31
#3      1 2017   20  17
#4      1  213    2  13
#5      2  256    2  56
#6      2 1031   10  31
#7      2 1517   15  17
#8      2  226    2  26
```

---

Or if it needs to only create a delimiter

```
tmp <- sub('(\\d{2})$', ':\\1', df$time)
tmp
#[1] "3:56"  "9:31"  "20:17" "2:13"  "2:56"  "10:31" "15:17" "2:26"
```

and then it can be separated in to two column with `read.table`

```
read.table(text = tmp, sep=":", header = FALSE, col.names = c('hour', 'min'))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), time = c(356L, 
931L, 2017L, 213L, 256L, 1031L, 1517L, 226L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
res<-strsplit(gsub("(\\d+(?=\\d{2,}))(\\d{1,})",
              "\\1:\\2",df$time,perl = T),":")
df$Minutes <- sapply(res,"[[",2)
df$Hr <- sapply(res,"[[",1)
df
```

Result:

```
 person time Minutes Hr
1      1  356      56  3
2      1  931      31  9
3      1 2017      17 20
4      1 2103      03 21
5      2  256      56  2
6      2 1031      31 10
7      2 1517      17 15
8      2 2206      06 22
```

Data:

```
df <-structure(list(person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), time = c(356L, 
931L, 2017L, 2103L, 256L, 1031L, 1517L, 2206L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show time in `HH:MM` format, probably we can use `sprintf` with `sub` to enter semicolon (`:`) in between

```
sub("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2",sprintf("%04d", df$time))
#[1] "03:56" "09:31" "20:17" "21:03" "02:56" "10:31" "15:17" "22:06"
```